# Angular2/4 ngFor directive does not allow variable assignment

Tags: angular, filter, ngfor

In my AngularJS app I used to do the following in my HTML templates:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in filtered = (users | filter:searchTerm | orderBy:firstName)">
```

Then I could use the variable "filtered" in my controller so that I had access to my filtered table row items.

Angular 2/4 does not allow this assignment so how would I be able to do this in Angular 2/4?

UPDATE:

Component:

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users = [];
  totalItems = 0;
  filteredUsers = [];
  filteredUser: User;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.users = data.data;
      },
      msg => console.error(`Error: ${msg.status} ${msg.statusText}`)
    );
  }

  trackItems(index, item){
    this.totalItems = index+1;
    this.filteredUsers.push(item); // <- This does not work? Should be able to push the item to my filteredUsers array?
    return item ? item.id : undefined;
  }
}
```

template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users | filterBy: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email']: searchTerm; trackBy: trackItems">
```

Error message:

```
UsersComponent.html:49 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/pages/users/users.component.ts.UsersComponent.trackItems [as _trackByFn] (users.component.ts:108)
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.check (core.es5.js:6857)
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.es5.js:6830)
    at NgForOf.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.es5.js:1669)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10837)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12330)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12269)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13130)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13071)
    at Object.View_UsersComponent_0._co [as updateDirectives] (UsersComponent.html:58)

UsersComponent.html:49 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 97, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let first = first; let last = last" >
//OR
<tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let even = even; let odd = odd" >

 //OR
 <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes; trackBy: trackHero" >
```

We can provide our own mechanism for tracking items in a list by using trackBy. We need to pass a function to trackBy, and the function takes a couple of arguments, which are an index and the current item:

```
@Component({
    selector:'heroes',
    template: `
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes; trackBy: trackHero" >
                <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
`
})
export class Heroes {

    heroes = HEROES;

    trackHero(index, hero) {
        console.log(hero);
        return hero ? hero.id : undefined;

    }


}
```

http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/

Comment: Thank you very much! One additional error I'm getting. I can't push the item to an array in my component inside the trackHero function. When I try to access a variable I have defined in my component inside trackHero it is saying it is undefined?

Comment: Please add the code to explain the question , if you think above answer is on point , so please accept to help others .

Comment: @DavidFinch make sure the array you are pushing to is defined , i am not sure how are you accessing the array , may be it is something related to scope of the variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as` with `*ngIf`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="users | filterBy:[...] as filteredUsers">
  <tr *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers">
```

But this creates a "variable" `filteredUsers` which is local to the template, and has nothing to do with the "controller". (Note also that the [Angular team recommends against filter and sort pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe).)

You cannot set a controller property in the context of a template expression such as that used in `*ngFor` or `*ngIf`. You can set it in an event handler, but that's a different situation:

```
<my-component (onToggle)="prop = !prop">
```

In general, it's preferable to put avoid putting too much logic in the template anyway. The template should restrict itself to what is necessary to get pixels up on the screen representing the state of the controller. When you need to calculate something or filter something, do that in the controller.

Comment: Thank you very much torazaburo! I did as you suggested, removed the pipe and filtered in my controller instead. Works perfectly!